# Identify anime with submarine under aerial attack

Tags: kaitei-daisensou

This is an anime movie (OAV?) I saw on a local TV station in the late 80's. It was dubbed in English and here's all that I remember about it:

- Set in a futuristic dystopian world.
- Hero was a young male with at least one additional male companion.
- They find a lost girl and decide to help her.
- After sometime they find her father who is the captain of a submarine.
- Among the crew is a fat chef who treats the hero and his band to a large feast.
- Sometime later, the submarine surfaces, probably to do some kind of maintenance. I remember scuba divers working around the sub.
- An enemy jet fighter finds them and starts strafing the submarine, killing several of the divers.
- The fat chef attempts to rescue some survivors but gets shot himself.
- The movie ends with the sub sinking but the hero and his friends surviving.

**EDIT:**

It is not any of the following *submarine* animes:

- Submarine Super 99
- Konpeki no Kantai
- Nadia of the Blue Seas
- Blue Noah
- Blue Submarine No. 6

Comment: Sounds kind of like Mars Daybreak, but that's not a show from the 80's

Comment: @JonLin - Yeah definitely not that one

Comment: Maybe it could be Submarine Super 99 OR Konpeki no Kantai  Those 2 are atleast the closest ones I could find using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_ships

Comment: @Dimitrimx - Not one of those two unfortunately

Comment: Isn't it "Nadia: The Secret of Blue Water" ? It's from the early 90s.

Comment: Nope. I know Nadia and it's not it.

Comment: You may check [List of Animated feature films list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animated_feature_films) maybe you can find it there...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to a very diligent redditor I was able to find it.

[image: The Great Navy Battle: 20,000 Miles of Love]

**海底大戦争 愛の20,000マイル

The Great Navy Battle: 20,000 Miles of Love**

Released by Tatsonoku in 1981. Apparently it was dubbed by Harmony Gold as **Undersea Encounter** but was never released for home video, which probably explains why there's almost no trace of it in the web except for a few cover images and brief synopses (mostly in Japanese).

Answer (score 0):

Could it be Marine Boy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marine_Boy It's from the 60's but is still shown on TV even now. If you look at the episode list there are several involving submarines. I haven't personally seen it myself.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is Super Atragon but its a 90s anime

[image]

Comment: You should try expanding your answer a bit, maybe some links or image. Also i believe it is not called Super atragon but atragon

Comment: Super atragon is the animated version of atragon

Comment: okay yeah thats my bad. thought the animated version was called the same ;)